# Trash icon and files have disappeared from the desktop after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, trash, desktop-icons

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 19.04, and after the restart, the trash icon and my Desktop files have disappeared from the UI. If I go to the **Desktop** folder from my personal folder, I can see the files, but my Desktop is empty.

How can I show my files in the Desktop again?

Comment: Please use full version numbers. More information: [Always use full Ubuntu version numbers (if you want to specify the version)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17941/always-use-full-ubuntu-version-numbers-if-you-want-to-specify-the-version) I guessed them this time, please [edit] if I made a mistake.

Comment: How did you finally manage to resolve this (if you actually did)? I have a similar problem after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. In my case whenever I try to change something to the desktop appearance e.g. adding a folder or changing the appearance through the tweaks-tool, this triggers the appearance of the icons(!).

Comment: Installing Tweaks and "Desktop icons" extension like vanadium says in their reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Gnome Tweaks ("Tweaks") from the software center. In Tweaks, click the extensions tab. Find the extension "Desktop icons" and enable it.

If you do not find the extension in Tweaks, it might not have been installed during your upgrade. In that case, install it from software, or with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`.

Background: In general, upgrading is not the very best way to update an Ubuntu version. An upgrade is not always without issues, in many cases small ones (like this probably), but sometimes major issues. That is why it is not possible to know whether your issue is due to the extension not being enabled, or the extension not being installed.

In 19.04, desktop icons are handled by a rather new Gnome Shell extension instead of by the file manager.

Comment: I ran the command to install the desktop icons extension and it is now installed but even after re-booting it doesn't appear in the Gnome Tweak Tool.