# Desktop icons in 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, desktop-icons

I have just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 and all of my links and icons have disappeared from my desktop. However when I look under ~/Desktop the documents are still there, they are just not actually showing up on the desktop itself. The links seem to have gone completely though.

I haven't had this problem with earlier upgrades.

Comment: Do you have the `desktop-icons` extension installed and activated? Refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1137600/480481

Comment: @pomsky I ran the command to install the desktop icons extension and it is now installed but even after re-booting it doesn't appear in the Gnome Tweak Tool.

Comment: You need to restart the gnome-shell with alt-f2, r, enter.

Comment: I'm using Wayland so that doesn't work. But surely a re-boot restarts the gnome-shell

Comment: I'd recommend not using Wayland... as it's a work in progress... and you'll have a lot more compatibility without it. And yes... a reboot should have worked for you also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop works slightly differently in 19.04, due to the removal of that function from the current gnome-shell. Progress moved backwards in this case, but they had reasons to remove it.

- There's a GNOME extension called `Desktop Icons`(https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/), once installed, it's found at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, make sure it's enabled.
- The **quick** way to recover some of the same operability is to use the `Files` application to create a new folder on the Desktop called "Work in Progress", or "pseudo Desktop", and then move all prior icons (except Home and Trash) from the Desktop into this new folder. Then close the `Files` app. Use this newly created folder like you used the Desktop in versions prior to 19.04.